# Boxed label with background color

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Howto plot a `boxed` `label` with a specific `background` color? (Like the legend box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
LABEL="label in a box"
set obj 10 rect at 0,0 size char strlen(LABEL), char 1 fc rgb "cyan"
set label 10 LABEL at 0,0 front center
plot sin(x)
```

Here's a [link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rectangle.html) to gnuplot's demo where I got the idea.

Of course, you can make the size of the box slightly bigger -- I find that it makes things look a little nicer:

```
set obj 10 rect at 0,0 size char strlen(LABEL)+1, char 1.5 fc rgb "cyan"
```

But that's up to you.