# Label-Style in Gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot

I use a Perl-script to make several graphs through piping a heredoc to Gnuplot (version 4.6 patchlevel 3). I have some problems to define labels in the desired manner. I want to:

- include variables in the label with the definition of the format (`sprintf`)
- use different labels for different plots
- show the labels in a box and show them in front

I don't know how to define the [format specifiers](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html) and I also had a look at the [label docu1](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?(gnuplot)label) [link isn't interpreted correctly] [label docu2](http://www.manpagez.com/info/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.4.3/gnuplot_259.php). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362440/boxed-label-with-background-color/15367793#15367793) shows a complicated way how to define the box and has to be set for every label.

Sorry for posting not just one exact question, but they are all concerning the labeling style.

My Gnuplot tests so far:

```
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "#FF4500"
set label 1 'Var1 = sprintf("%5.3f",$Var1)' at graph 0.8, graph 0.95 front font 'Times-Roman,10'
plot "file.dat" u 1:2 ls 1
```

My problems:

- The sprintf isn't interpreted in the output.
- I can't use the different labels like I use the different `ls` (linestyle).
- The boxing frame of the label has to be defined for every single label in a complicated manner.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets see how to get the things sorted:

Using `sprintf` works like this:

```
set label 1 sprintf("Var1 = %5.3f",Var1) at ...
```

or

```
set label 1 'Var1 = '.sprintf("%5.3f", Var1) at ...
```

Boxed labels are supported only in the current development version 4.7. You could misuse the key to get a boxed label (if you don't need it otherwise):

```
set key opaque box samplen -1 at graph 0.8, graph 0.95 font 'Times-Roman,10'
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 ls 1 title sprintf('Var1 = %5.3f', Var1)
```

Comment: Thx Christoph. Stupid mistake by me with the `sprintf`. Unfortunately I need the key, so I can't use that. And do I really have to `unset label` after each plot and redefine it (because I need different labels for each plot)? I would love to stick to the definition like I do with `set style line X` for X plots. Isn't this possible for labels and other features?

Comment: @bashophil I don't really get, what you need. If you define a very lengthy label, you can replace later only the text: `set label 1 'first' at graph 0.8,graph 0.8 tc rgb 'green'; plot sin(x); set label 1 'second'; replot`. See, that the 'second' label is also green an at the same position. Otherwise you may need to play around with `set macro` or `evaluate`. Maybe you can edit your question to show in more detail you needs (using just functions instead of data).

Comment: Hi Christoph. Thx for the help. I like the definition of the linestyle, so I can just call the defined style with e.g. `ls 1` when I set the plot command. I thought this would be maybe possible with something like `set style label 1` and use this later. Nonetheless, thank you very much, I can work with this :)